# Settings to add programmatically created product to store in multi-store site

Tags: product, multistore, magento-1

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to add products into a store in a multi-website, multi store site.  I am basing the script on one which works fine on single store projects so I am guessing that the error is down to something like store and website ids or  "current store" settings.  The product appears in the DB and I can load it from a script - however it does not appear in the backend or front end of the site. Can anyone assist in explaining the correct combination of store Ids (or what else I might be missing).

Here is the site/store structure:

```
Main Website (1)
UK Site (2)
    -> Uk store (2)
EU Site (3)
    -> Spanish store (3)
    -> German store (4)
    -> French store (5)
```

Here is are the main/important bits of the script.  In this instance I am trying to save the product to the UK site (website id 2) and UK store (store id 2):

```
Mage::app();
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
//NOTE: have also tried Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(2));
$cstore = Mage::app()->getStore(); //quick check

/* when setCurrentStore is set to 2 $cstore includes:
* [_data:protected] => Array
*       (
*           [store_id] => 2
*           [code] => uk
*           [website_id] => 2
*           [group_id] => 2
*           [name] => UK
*           [sort_order] => 1
*           [is_active] => 1
*       )
*
*    when setCurrentStire is done with ADMIN_STORE_ID, we get this
*
*        [_data:protected] => Array
*        (
*            [store_id] => 0
*            [code] => admin
*            [website_id] => 0
*            [group_id] => 0
*            [name] => Admin
*            [sort_order] => 0
*            [is_active] => 1
*        )
*/

//attributeSetID is  pulled out but for the purpose of this..
$attributeSetId= 4; // default

//dummy item
$item = array("name"=>"test product","id"=>"123456");

//I have tried using setWebsiteId and setWebsiteIds  (and same for storeId)

$this->magObject = Mage::getModel("catalog/product"); //new     
$this->magObject ->setTypeId('grouped')
        ->setSku($item["id"])
        ->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId)
        ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        //->setWebsiteIds(array(2))
        ->setWebsiteId(2)
        //->setStoreIds(array(2))
        ->setStoreId(2)
        ->setName($item["name"])
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
        ->setMetaTitle($item["name"])
        ->setMetaDescription('test meta description')
        ->setDescription('This is a long description')
        ->setTaxClassId(0) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
        ->setPrice(9999.99)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->setWeight(4.0000)
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
        ->setStockData(
            array(
            'is_in_stock' => 1,
            'qty' => 99999,
            'manage_stock' => 0,
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0
            )
        );


$this->magObject->save();
$newRangeId = $this->magObject->getId(); // this correctly returns the new Id of the product in the DB, which can then be loaded and updated
$this->echoOut(" - New Range ID is ".$newRangeId . " - now updating");
```

**UPDATE**:

I added in the code to set the `CategoryIds` and the items do appear in the admin now - all sorted.  One would think that you could have a product not in a category (yet).

Comment: Do I need to set a category ID at this stage?

Comment: I have seen that there is no entry for the newly created product(s) in catalog_product_website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was not assigned the products to a category or categories.

By adding in

```
$this->magObject->setCategoryIds(array(#some ids here));
```

The objects appeared in the admin.

By changing `setWebsiteId(2)` and `setStoreId(2)` back to `setWebsiteIds(array(1, 2))` and `setStoreIds(array(1, 2))` the products were then correctly assigned in the admin too.

Seems a bit wrong that you have to assign a product to a category just to get it to show - that may be something one wanted to do at a later date, but there you go.